# vmware nat internet connection

Tags: nat, internet, vmware-server

Host:
Windows Server 2008 / VMWare Server 2
Has Internet connection
ip: 172.17.62.1 (NAT adapter)
no gateway, no dns

Guest: 
Windows Server 2003 
ip: 172.17.62.2 (NAT)
gateway 172.17.62.5 (set in VMware network manager for NAT)

Host and guest can see each other, but guest have no internet connection (only ping by ip)
In what may be the problem?

```
HOST
Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-08
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f1c1:3518:abb4:c05%24(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.17.67.1(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 486559830
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-13-CF-8C-9F-40-61-86-2B-8F-AD
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

GUEST

```
DNS-suffix . . : 
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Accelerated AMD PCNet Adapter
   Physical. . . . . . . . . : 00-0C-29-71-A5-43
   DHCP  . . . . . . . . . . . : no
   ip  . . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.17.67.2
   subnet mask . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   gateway . . . . . . . . . . : 172.17.67.5
   DNS . . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
```

All firewalls are down, I can ping hosts, but no telnet connection - telnet google.com 80

---

Workaround with proxy server installed on host.
All guests can access to internet
I don't know why vmware server cannot share internet in this configuration

Comment: You're going to have to add a LOT more detail if you expect this to be answered.

Comment: What do you mean by "Only ping by IP"? If you can successfully ping in or out, it means you have an internet connection.

Comment: If you can ping Internet hosts by IP, perhaps you have a DNS problem?  Not sure what exactly you mean.

Comment: I supposed that DNS problem ,but how to investigate it?

Comment: What details should I provide?

Comment: Check the results of running ipconfig /all in a cmd.exe window.  Does it have a DNS server set?  If not, set one manually in the TCP/IP properties.

Comment: there is no DNS server, which server should I use?

Comment: I'd say use the DNS your ISP provides.  You can also use Google's 8.8.8.8?

Comment: Ok, now I can ping any hosts, but still no connection (at browser as example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that was a vmware problem with vmnat.exe
http://communities.vmware.com/thread/273614